# Improper data value stored in cloud firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using `firebase-admin` Python SDK to store data into Firestore. However, when I'm calling `add()` method in my collection reference the data gets stored to Firestore but its format is not proper.

```py
message = {
     u'avatar_url': get_avatar_url(user),
     u'timestamp': get_utc_timestamp(),
     u'event': u'adding_avatar' 
}
```

```py
def add_data(message):
  coll_ref.add(message)
```

When I look into the Firestore collection, I find that the data stored is of the format:

```
{
  avatar_url: aHR0cDovL2,
  timestamp: 1569404588,
  event: 'adding_avatar'
}
```

I expect the data to look like this(when viewing from Firebase console):

```
{
  avatar_url: 'https://localhost:8000/images/avatar.png',
  timestamp: 1569404588,
  event: 'adding_avatar'
}
```

The type of `avatar_url` is `blob`. I don't know why is this happening? What is the standard way to add a python dictionary as a payload to Firestore with appropriate datatype?

Comment: What happens if you print() the return value of get_avatar_url() and get_utc_timestamp()? The value stored looks like a timestamp!

Comment: get_avatar_url() gives me a url which is of string type `http://localhost:8000/images/avatar.png` and get_utc_timestamp() gives me this `1569405361000`.

Comment: What do you expect the data to look like?

Comment: 1. Firestore doesn't have a blob data type (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). 2. I would say the problem is within get_avatar_url()

Comment: Yes, you're right. It turns out that I'm running Python 2.7 and `get_avatar_url()` should actually return a string of `unicode` type, so I prefixed the string response with `u'https://localhost:8000/images/avatar.png` and everything worked perfectly.